# Docker image in Release Pipeline Azure DevOps Failed with error code 145

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I've release pipeline where I wanted to build docker image getting this error

[image]

Here is my Docker File

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pulling the wrong image for the build container. It needs to be an SDK image. So line 7 should be

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build
```